# ActionScript 3.0 version control library?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, hgsubversion

is there any library for Action Script 3 that allows my AIR application to function like a version control (svn or cvs or something similar) client?

I just want to use the download functionality. my app relies on some folder and file structure that may change through updates and it'd be great if i could simply manage a subversion repository online and the application would automatically sync it's filestructure to this repository.

Comment: Can you explain it in detail? if you are thinking about FileManager like Application, please read article
[Creating a File Manager in Adobe Air](http://www.spltech.co.uk/blog/adobe-air/creating-a-file-manager-in-adobe-flex) or if you wants to integrate SVN with Air/ActionScript please read this blog [Accessing SVN Repositories with ActionScript](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2009/01/20/accessing-svn-repositories-with-actionscript/) Hopefully this will helps

Comment: what I want is something like functionality `FileRepository.checkout()`, or `FileRepository.update()` and that it automatically updates the local repository then. the linked articles discuss other things. I don't need filemanagement and I also don't need the revision history. I just need the 'update' functionality to work, such that my application on startup can check whether the local filestructure is at the latest revision and if not, update it

Comment: hmm right, but i think you should use 2nd option to update LOCAL REPOSITORY using SVN because its help full in checking diff and update Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Using NativeProcess in AIR, you could make background calls to svn or cvs by command line: 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html

As Imran also pointed out, you could use Doug McCune's SVN library to get revision history via AS3 and then pull what you want via a NativeProcess call:
http://dougmccune.com/blog/2009/01/20/accessing-svn-repositories-with-actionscript/

Comment: hello and thanks. This would require the user to install additional software. I'd like my application to handle vereything without relying on other processes. it doesn't need to be a full featured versioning client. I just need the update functionality. Of course I could manually check the history, then dig into the specifications of svn to figure out how to check which files differ on my harddisk and then downloading and overwriting them. but of course it would be convenient if a versioning library already existed that can handle that for me

Comment: You could if you wanted to, but that would require you to implement your own SVN client from scratch using the available document specs and custom socket (ie. a BUTTLOAD of extra work).  You're better off without out.  There are better solutions out there.